# What does "score" mean in the following bitcoin node info printout?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

This is the response from a getnetworkinfo command;

```
"relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
    {
      "address": "*qd.onion",
      "port": 8333,
      "score": 4
    }
  ],
  "warnings": ""
```